# Default View for "Save as" window in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, desktop-customization, save-as

So I know very well how to customize all the folders views in Windows to a very specific way. Just set up a folder the way you want it to look and use the good old fashioned "Apply to Folders" button.

Set folder the way you want it>Go to view tab> select options>Change folder and search options>Click the view tab in the new window>click apply to folders button

And boom! Now all your folders look like the one you customized unless...

You're looking at them  through the save as" window.

If I open any application and click "save as" I see that my customization are not reflected here.

For example I want all my files and folders to be sorted by "date modified". So I do the above customization and everywhere I go everything is sorted by "Date Modified" unless I open a save as Window. In the save as window everything is back to the default of being sorted by name.

So the "Save as" Window seem to be operating independently  of the regular file explore at least as far as its view settings go.

The crazy thing is I could have sworn this used to work, but every computer I try it on seems determined to be prove me wrong and or crazy.

Can anyone help? Inside the "Save as" window. the same Folder options buttons are greyed out. In there a registry hack? Anything?

Thanks in advance for any advice

-Dave

Comment: The look, starting directory, are all programmed defined

Comment: Related question (still no answers as of now):
https://superuser.com/questions/1546912/windows-10-file-selector-how-do-i-specify-details-view-as-the-default

Answer (score 0):

From my experience of *NT4* thru *Win7* those dialogs always showed by default the **"icon" view** (filenames with icons only, listed in multiple columns growing horizontally) - the display view could be customized (by clicking on the buttons), but never remembered. However, programs that invoke those dialogs are able to do that for the user (or i.e by display the **"details" view** by default). Over the time I encountered only few programs actually making use of this, tho.

This all refers to [GetOpenFilename()](https://www.google.ca/search?q=GetOpenFilename&tbm=isch). Don't know if the [IFileOpenDialog](https://www.google.ca/search?q=IFileOpenDialog&tbm=isch) type even let programs do this as well.