# Windows 10 file selector: How do I specify details view as the default?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, default-settings

Whenever the user needs to select a file - for loading into a program, or saving, or any other reason - the file selector dialog ensues. In Windows 10, it is like a miniature Windows Explorer (or File Explorer as it used to be called) with a filename mask (e.g., *.txt) and a filename field.

The bulk of the dialog shows the files in the current folder in *Medium icons* view. I prefer the *Details* view, so the files can quickly be sorted by clicking on one of the column headings. To change the view, I have to pull down a menu and drag a slider - additional mouse clicks that I'd rather avoid. However, my choice will be forgotten next time a file selector is open.

Can I change the file selector default view to *Details* or anything else?

Comment: One thing to note is MS Office uses it's own dialogs not Windows dialogs.

Comment: I am referring to the generic file selector; not the special one used by MS Office.

Comment: Just making sure you knew they are different.

Comment: See my answer here https://superuser.com/questions/1527380/how-do-i-stop-windows-10-from-listing-files-in-groups-ever/1527415#1527415. The thing to note is it is also about __the path you took to the folder__. So `Desktop` has different settings to `%userprofile%\Desktop`. That is probably important when you open a folder window on a specific folder.

Answer (score 2):

Just like folders in Explorer, the first time a folder's contents are displayed in a *Common Dialog* (Open/Save/SaveAs), the icon mode and other view settings are determined by the default view for the *FolderType* assigned to the folder. This may be the standard Windows defaults or custom defaults set via **Apply to Folders**. Those view settings (and any modifications) are then saved alongside the saved folder view used by **Explorer**:
[image]
The saved views are specific to a single folder, so the icon mode could change if you navigate from a folder that saved an **Icon** view to a folder that saved a **Tiles** view. If folders don't seem to retain their views, you may have hit the max (5000) and need to delete all saved views to restore normal behavior. This **PowerShell** code can be copied to a **PowerShell** window to query the number of saved views:

```
((gp "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU").Nodeslots).count
```

So if your dialogs are defaulting to icon view, I'm guessing they might be using the **Pictrues** *FolderType*. If you don't want to set the default view for all folders uisng the **Pictrues** *FolderType*, you're stuck with changing the dialog to **Details** after it's opened. But:

1. You might find it quicker to right-click in the background and select **View > Details**:[image]
2. Once you've set a folder's dialog view to **Details**, it *should* be remembered.

A small **PowerShell** script could modify existing saved views to ensure they're in **Detials** mode, but since you said your changes don't seem to be remembered, I'm waiting to hear your reply regarding the saved view count.

### EDIT:

The following code will list the *FolderTypes* that have had a custom view set via **Apply to Folders**:

```
$Defaults = 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Streams\Defaults'
$FT      = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes'
(gi $defaults).Property | Select @{N = 'ID'; E = {$_}}, @{N = 'Name'; E = {(gp "$FT\$_").CanonicalName}}
```

Here's a list of the FolderType IDs that **Explorer** queries under **HKCU...\Streams\Defaults**:

```
HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Streams\Defaults
ID                                     Name
--                                     ----
{885A186E-A440-4ADA-812B-DB871B942259} Downloads
{5C4F28B5-F869-4E84-8E60-F11DB97C5CC7} Generic
{7D49D726-3C21-4F05-99AA-FDC2C9474656} Documents
{94D6DDCC-4A68-4175-A374-BD584A510B78} Music
{B3690E58-E961-423B-B687-386EBFD83239} Pictures
{5FA96407-7E77-483C-AC93-691D05850DE8} Videos
{4F01EBC5-2385-41F2-A28E-2C5C91FB56E0} StorageProviderGeneric
{DD61BD66-70E8-48DD-9655-65C5E1AAC2D1} StorageProviderDocuments
{672ECD7E-AF04-4399-875C-0290845B6247} StorageProviderMusic
{71D642A9-F2B1-42CD-AD92-EB9300C7CC0A} StorageProviderPictures
{51294DA1-D7B1-485B-9E9A-17CFFE33E187} StorageProviderVideos
{DB2A5D8F-06E6-4007-ABA6-AF877D526EA6} AccountPictures
{DE2B70EC-9BF7-4A93-BD3D-243F7881D492} Contacts
{24CCB8A6-C45A-477D-B940-3382B9225668} HomeFolder
{C4D98F09-6124-4FE0-9942-826416082DA9} UsersLibraries
{D674391B-52D9-4E07-834E-67C98610F39D} Programs
{CD0FC69B-71E2-46E5-9690-5BCD9F57AAB3} UserFiles
{0B0BA2E3-405F-415E-A6EE-CAD625207853} Searches
```

This code will list the *FolderTypes* that are being used by the Common Dialogs. That may help you determine where the icon view is coming from:

```
$Bags = 'HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags'
$FT   = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes'
gci $Bags -recurse  |
    Where PSChildName -like '{*}' |
    Where PSParentPath -match 'ComDlg' |
Select -expand PSChildName -unique |
Select @{N = 'ID'  ; E = {$_}},
       @{N = 'Name'; E = {(gp "$FT\$_").CanonicalName}}
```

Comment: Your answer contains useful information and is quite informed, so I've learned a few things, but no solution yet.

I have either _Details_ or _List_ as default folder views in Windows Explorer, set to be the same for "All folders of this type" via View->Options.
I just checked: "picture" folders (where "Picture Tools" appears in the ribbon) currently display as _List_ in my system.
Your script counts 3762 saved views, so I'm still well under 5000. So, the Common Dialog apparently doesn't use the view for "picture" folders, nor does it save view settings for individual folders.

Comment: I've used RegEdit to view and change the LogicalMode and Mode values for Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Local
Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\13\ComDlg\{5C4F28B5-F869-4E84-
8E60-F11DB97C5CC7}, hoping it would be the key holding the view mode for the Common Dialog, but it appears not to be the case.

Comment: I'm going to add some code to my post tist what _FolderTypes_ have a custom default set via **Apply to Folders**

Comment: In the edit you mention above, a `Shell` key holds an Explorer view. Dialog views will be in keys named `ComDlg` or `ComDlgLegacy`.

Comment: I also added code that lists the _FolderTypes_ in use by the Common Dialogs that have saved views.

Answer (score 1):

FYI: July 2023: I wanted my files to show as lists of file details. I was able to accomplish this by

1. selecting a folder (in windows explorer)
2. right clicking on folder and selected "properties"
3. selected the "Customize" tab
4. In the "Optimize this folder for" drop down, selected "Documents" option
5. Selected the checkbox "Also apply this template to all subfolders"
6. Pressed the "Apply" button

When I look at files w/in subfolders, they show as a detail list.

Comment: Hello, your answer, if it's even an answer, shouldn't contain questions.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I have removed the questionable text. This solution appears to have solved this problem for me. Other answers haven’t worked. This can be an alternative solution if others have similar experiences.

Answer (score 0):

To set the default view for File Explorer in Windows 10:

1. Launch File Explorer (Windows Key + E)
2. Select the View Tab and select the desired view layout
3. Click the File Tab and select the "Change Folder and Search Options"
4. In the Folder Options window select the View tab
5. Click on the Apply to Folders button
6. Accept the "Do you want all folders of this type to match this folder's view settings" dialog.
7. Click OK to exit the Folder Options window

Note, depending on how a program is written these default settings might not be used, but they will apply to the OS File Explorer.

Comment: I am referring to the file selector (the dialog box you usually see when you choose _Open_ or _Save As_ commands), not to the ordinary File Explorer.